# Is my closed question of any value to future visitors

Tags: discussion

I don’t have a problem with my question [What is the advantage to showing the Trusted Site Logo on your website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/140775/what-is-the-advantage-to-showing-the-trusted-site-logo-on-your-website) being closed.

Should I delete it or does it have some future value?

Answer (score 3):

We generally leave duplicate questions un-deleted.  They may phrase the question differently enough that they will appear in search when the original question didn't. They then act as a signpost to the answer the searcher wants.

Related on the main meta site: [How many duplicates (if any) are enough to justify deletion of a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361371/how-many-duplicates-if-any-are-enough-to-justify-deletion-of-a-question)